# How can I make this UDPSocket object global so I can use it in other functions?

Tags: c++

In my code I create the socket object like so:

```
UDPSocket sock(&eth);
```

"eth" is of type EthernetInterface.

All is well for using the "sock" functions inside the function where I created the socket object, however I need to access the same socket to receive UDP packets in a different function.

It can't go with the other global variables because of the function in it, and I have tried setting `UDPSocket socket;` in globals and then

```
UDPSocket s(&eth);
sock = s;
```

This seems to crash the ARM device I am running it on. I don't want to create a UDPObject and then have to pass it as a parameter to every function every time they are called.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a global pointer like

```
UDPSocket *socket;
```

and init it at the beginning:

```
int main() {
     socket = new UDPSocket(&eth);
     //other code
}
```

or at least before you're using it. And don't forget to delete it afterwards

Edit:
Comment considred using `std::unique_ptr<UDPSocket>` and to init it with `std::make_unique<UDPSocket>(&eth)`

Comment: Decent solution, but consider using `std::unique_ptr<UDPSocket> socket;` and `socket = std::make_unique<UDPSocket>(&eth);` to nail down ownership and get [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii) working for you